# Why does MeshReflectorMaterial (ported to vanilla) cause offset reflection when normalmap is applied?

Tags: three.js

In THREE.js I'm using the MeshReflectorMaterial [ported from r3f/drei](https://github.com/0beqz/vanilla-threejs-meshreflectormaterial-example) and it works fine, however when applying a normalmap the reflection becomes offset on the z axis, breaking the effect. I've adjusted the depthScale and other parameters to no avail - any ideas? This issue is also incidentally [flagged on drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/1558).

**Simplified Implementation:**

```
const groundNormal = textureLoader.load('static/terrain-normal.jpg');
groundNormal.wrapS = groundNormal.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
groundNormal.repeat.set(5, 5);


plane.material.setValues({

   normalMap: groundNormal,
   normalScale: new THREE.Vector2(0.2, 0.2),

})
```

**[Source code for the material](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0beqz/vanilla-threejs-meshreflectormaterial-example/master/src/MeshReflectorMaterial.js)**

Many thanks!

[image]